# Running ES2016 unit tests with Jest in BitBucket's Pipelines

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, bitbucket, jestjs

I have a webapp I created using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I've already ejected the project. Now I'm trying to configure Jest, Enzyme and all the rest to play well with BitBucket's Pipelines, to be able to run it in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` config.

Locally, the tests are executed fine (using `npm test`), but when running the code on BitBucket, I'm getting the following error:

```
npm test
> sicj@0.1.0 test /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Cannot find module 'enzyme' from 'App.test.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:144:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:3:41)
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.323s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

So it's just failing to find `enzyme` module. To check if the module is installed correctly, I run `ls node_modules` and then `ls node_modules/enzyme`. Here is the result:

```
+ ls node_modules/enzyme
CHANGELOG.md     ReactWrapper.js            karma.conf.js  src
CONTRIBUTING.md  ShallowWrapper.js          mount.js       test
INTHEWILD.md     book.json                  node_modules       withDom.js
LICENSE.md       docs                       package.json
MAINTAINERS      example-test.sh            render.js
README.md        install-relevant-react.sh  shallow.js
```

Well, it looks good to me.

What am I doing wrong? I'm just starting with React and generally with front-end development. I don't get what's the difference between running it locally (on my desktop) and on BitBucket.

I've already tried:

- removing `node_modules` folder and rerunning `npm install`
- applying the pointer in [ReferenceError on enzyme import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761861/referenceerror-on-enzyme-import)

but no change in behavior.

Answer (score 3):

are you running npm install? I have an example create-react-app that works with following setup:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install -g yarnpkg
          - export CI=true
          - yarn install
          - yarn test
          - yarn build
```

Comment: Yes, I run npm install. I use npm, not yarn, so your example doesn't help much. I think the problem lies in enzyme somehow not being seen by the unit test framework.

Answer (score 0):

When `enzyme` builds properly there will be a `build` folder.
For me, I installed React 15 and then had to install `react-addons-test-utils`.

Then I reinstalled `enzyme` and everything works (you could probably trigger the post-install build step of enzyme manually, but `npm i --save-dev enzyme` seemed simplest to me).